# Выбрать строки, где сумма значений ячеек не превышает определенное число

Tags: mysql

Есть остаток товара #1 например 7шт.
На этот товар есть 16 строк в таблице приходов. с разными количествами и например 6 строк в таблице расходов
В итоге зная конечный остаток мне нужно сформировать запрос к таблице приходов начиная с последнего и выбрать только те строки которые включают этот остаток.
Например последние приходы
строка 13 - 2шт
строка 14 - 4шт
строка 15 - 2шт
должен выбрать строка 15 2шт и цену взять прихода
строка 14 4шт и цену
и строка 13 1шт и цену прихода..
как реализовать такой запрос в базу данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, в комментариях подсказали, что [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) не поддерживает синтаксис приведённый в первой части ответа. Также замечу, что возможно задачу можно решить с помощью хранимых процедур, или изменением архитектурного подхода. Ну или СУБД))

---

**Для СУБД поддерживающих стандарт SQL-2008**

Для решения задачи необходим запрос с использованием выражения `over(partition by...`, который позволит получать накопительную сумму прихода по товару. Обратите внимание в `(partition by ...)` добавлена сортировка `order by p.prihoddate desc` по убыванию даты прихода, чтобы накопление шло по мере уменьшения "свежести" прихода. Далее во внешнем запросе мы отсекаем `where nsum - prihod < 7` те суммы, которые перевалили за наш остаток. Обратите внимание, что в условии присутствует вычитание, это для того чтобы частично израсходованный приход вошел в выборку. Далее, нам нужно посчитать остатки для прихода, и тут приходится прибегнуть к условному оператору `case when nsum < 7 then prihod else prihod - (nsum - 7) end ostatok`, надеюсь вы без проблем подберёте аналог в [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Суть условия, что для нерасходованных приходов выводим остаток равный приходу, а для частично израсходованного отнимаем разницу между накопительной суммой и общим остатком по товару.
  Извините, тестировал на [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)

```
select tovarid,
   case
     when nsum < 7 then
      prihod
     else
      prihod - (nsum - 7)
   end ostatok,
   prihodprice,
   prihoddate
from (select p.*,
           sum(p.prihod) over
             (partition by p.tovarid 
              order by p.prihoddate desc) nsum
      from prihods p
     where p.tovarid = 1)
where nsum - prihod < 7
```

Исходные данные для запроса

[image: Исходные данные для запроса]

Выдаёт

[image: выдача]

---

**Решение для более ранних стандартов SQL**

Но ведь накопительную сумму можно взять и по другому - добавив ещё один уровень подзапроса.

```
select tovarid,
   case
     when psum + prihod < 7 then
      prihod
     else
      (7 - psum )
   end ostatok,
   prihodprice,
   prihoddate
from (select p.*,
         nvl((select sum(p2.prihod)
           from prihods p2
           where p2.prihoddate > p.prihoddate
           and p2.tovarid = p.tovarid),0) psum
      from prihods p
     where p.tovarid = 1)
where psum < 7
```

Обратите внимание накопительная сумма теперь взята сразу без учета прихода текущей строки, поэтому немного изменились условие отбора `psum < 7` и условный оператор `case when psum + prihod < 7 then prihod else (7 - psum ) end ostatok`. Теперь я не вижу препятствий для выполнения запроса на [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). На сколько он оптимален судить не берусь. Заметьте, что в выражении вычисления суммы добавлен оператор `nvl(...,0)` в [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) в случае когда первый параметр null, он возвращает второй параметр, в остальных случаях первый. Он нам нужен, чтобы проставить как psum значение 0, когда самый внутренний запрос не вернёт ни одной строки. Аналогом `nvl` в [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) является `IFNULL`

**P.S.** Вот казалось бы и обошли нехватку оконных функций в [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), но верхний запрос можно было без проблем переписать на выборку сразу по нескольким товарам, а нижний уже сложней. Ну и оптимальность в верхнем наверняка выиграет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42946/discussion-on-answer-by-3per---mysql-----).